# Where is the problem in this jenkins file?

Tags: php, jenkins-pipeline

```
pipeline{
    agent any

    stages{
        stage("deploy to remote"){
            steps{
                sh "scp -r /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/php/m root@192.168.221.130:/var/www/html/nbaquateck/ -P 2222"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a jenkins pipeline for a php project.

Comment: Is there a specific error or problem you'd like to tell us about, that you're experiencing when trying to use this code, so that we have some idea what we might be looking for? See also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?
artifact is your deployment package.
You must add your ssh key to destination server.

```
scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $artifact root@192.168.221.130:/var/www/html/nbaquateck/$artifact
```